# Box2d & Cocos2d properly point of colision

Tags: cocos2d-iphone, box2d-iphone

I have collision detection in my game. Now I need point of collison. 
I get it with:

```
int numPoints = contact.b2contact->GetManifold()->pointCount;
b2WorldManifold worldManifold;
contact.b2contact->GetWorldManifold( &worldManifold );
for (int i = 0; i < numPoints; i++)
{
    NSLog(@"%@" NSStringFormCGPoint(ccp(worldManifold.points[i].x,worldManifold.points[i].y));
}
```

This log shows position but in box2d standards. How I should properly convert it to Cocos2d v2 cords? Because multiply by PTM_RATIO not working very well.

### UPDATE

At this moment I came up with this.

```
b2Manifold* mainfold = contact->GetManifold();
int numPoints = mainfold->pointCount;

    for (int i=0; i<numPoints; i++) {
        b2ManifoldPoint *p = mainfold->points;
        NSLog(@"Dot:%@",NSStringFromCGPoint(ccp(p->localPoint.x * PTM_RATIO, p->localPoint.y * PTM_RATIO);));
    }
```

But that shows correct point only for one body.

Answer (score 0):

I think your first example was correct, but you were not properly converting the points to world points.  Something like this might work (I'm not at my computer to test it out, but I think this will give you the right direction anyway.

```
int numPoints = contact.b2contact->GetManifold()->pointCount;
b2WorldManifold worldManifold;
contact.b2contact->GetWorldManifold( &worldManifold );
for (int i = 0; i < numPoints; i++)
{
    b2Vec2 worldPoint = worldManifold.points[i]->GetWorldPoint();
    NSLOG(@"(%f,%f)", worldPoint.x*PTM_RATIO, worldPoint.y*PTM_RATIO);
}
```

Comment: I can't find anything close to `worldManifold.points[i]->GetWorldPoint();`

Comment: I was looking in the Box2D manual and found the GetWorldPoint() in the manifold section.  I have only actually used body->GetWorldPoint() but I thought it might be something similar.

Comment: It looks like my object is created in total mess up. Now I works with `GetBody()->GetWorldCenter()` convert them to CGPoint and work with distance and differences in position. It's more universal. If some want hear about it, please let me know. Thank @Sylvan for your time :)